# Looping with A Factor in R

Tags: r, loops

So this code fills in the values of the vector `Bone` according to the value of the factor `bonegrp`. I would like to accomplish this in a more concise manner.

Thanks!

```
v <- dat$bonegrp=="Bone2"  
Bone[v] <- "Gast 1"  
v <- dat$Bonegrp=="Bone3"  
Bone[v] <- "Gast 2"  
v <- dat$Bonegrp=="Bone4"  
Bone[v] <- "Vert1"  
v <- dat$Bonegrp=="Bone5"  
Bone[v] <- "Vert2"  
v <- dat$Bonegrp=="Bone6"  
Bone[v] <- "Femur"  
v <- dat$Bonegrp=="Bone7"  
Bone[v] <- "Tibia"  
v <- dat$Bonegrp=="Bone8"   
Bone[v] <- "Meta."  
v <- dat$Bonegrp=="Bone9"  
Bone[v] <- "Phal."  
v <- dat$Bonegrp=="Bone10"  
Bone[v] <- "PCau."  
v <- dat$Bonegrp=="Bone11"  
Bone[v] <- "MCau."  
v <- dat$Bonegrp=="Bone12"  
Bone[v] <- "DCau.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there are only 12 levels in Bonegrp then you could see if this works (edited per additional info regarding data structure):

```
Bone <- c(NA, "Gast 1", "Gast 2", "Vert1", "Vert2", "Femur","Tibia", "Meta.", 
          "Phal.", "PCau.", "MCau.", "DCau.")[as.numeric(dat$Bonegrp)]
```

It is basically using a vector and looking up the proper string based on the numeric equivalent of Bonegrp. You really *should* provide more information about your data. Just provided code is often not enough.

Comment: That definitely worked. Thanks a lot. I'm not exactly sure why, but I'll figure that out later!

Comment: Oops...Actually that did not work. The data is ex0523 from package "Sleuth2". basically I would like Bone to be a vector of length 52 with entries according to the value of the corresponding entry for "Bonegrp"

Comment: Think of the [ ] operator as the firing chamber of a machine-gun and every instance of dat$Bonegrp triggers an instance of the selection vector based on the value of the particular bullet that is passing through the `[]`-chamber. Yeh, I know. Trigger happy Americans. Hey, I don't even own a gun :-)

Comment: @Michael & @Dwin - the code above doesn't "work" because 1. there is a missing parens before closing the `c()` and 2, there are only 11 bones listed...in the code above, Michael started at "Bone2" so you can pad with NA or whatever is appropriate and everything should line up. Otherwise the code works as intended and does what you want.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help guys. Bone1 was supposed to be for "Rib".... So the [] operator is grabbing the numerical values of dat$Bonegrp and assigning the appropriate value from the c() list then?

Answer (score 3):

```
match=data.frame(bonegrp=c('Bone2','Bone3','Bone24','Bone5','Bone6','Bone7','Bone8','Bone9','Bone10','Bo
ne11','Bone12'),type=c('Gast 1','Gast 1','Vert1','Vert2','Femur','Tibia','Meta.','Phal','Pcau.','Mcau.','DCau'))

new_data=merge(dat,match,by='bonegrp')
```