# iteration over a factor extracting specific elements

Tags: r

So I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822399/looping-with-a-factor-in-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249317/r-display-a-counter-for-loops-across-one-display-line), and can't seem to find a good example of a way to loop or iterate over a factor (or are their other / better ways to do this?).  I have a data frame for which I have:

```
> head(frame)
    x1     x2     DateTime
  1 100   5   2010-06-01 05:32:46
  2 105   3   2010-06-01 05:32:23
  3 47    20  2010-06-01 05:32:34
  4 56    6   2010-06-01 05:33:16
  5 98    11  2010-06-01 05:54:12
  6 84    9   2010-06-01 05:54:05
```

and I can create a factor based on time like so: `fact <- cut(frame$DateTime, "1 hour")` from there, how would I go about extracting the first and last elements of frame$x2 given the factor I've created? (or for that matter, the nth element of the cut).

would it be something like:

```
test <- split(frame$x2, fact)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "extract" the nth element (i.e. do you want it in the same object, a new object, do you want something the same length as the original object, etc.).

I would use `ave` because it operates on factor groups.  Note that this assumes that your data.frame is sorted by `frame$DateTime`.

```
frame <- structure(list(
  x1 = c(100L, 105L, 47L, 56L, 98L, 84L),
  x2 = c(5L, 3L, 20L, 6L, 11L, 9L),
  DateTime = structure(c(1275388366, 1275388343, 1275388354, 1275388396,
    1275389652, 1275389645), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),
  fact = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
    .Label = "2010-06-01 05:00:00", class = "factor")),
    .Names = c("x1", "x2", "DateTime", "fact"),
  row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

transform(frame, firstx2=ave(x2, fact, FUN=function(x) x[1]),
                 lastx2 =ave(x2, fact, FUN=function(x) x[length(x)]))

# These lines do the same as the `transform` line(s)
frame$firstx2 <- ave(frame$x2, frame$fact, FUN=function(x) x[1])
frame$lastx2  <- ave(frame$x2, frame$fact, FUN=function(x) x[length(x)])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, and I apologize if I was unclear.  Yes, frame$DateTime is sorted, and I guess I am trying to extract the nth element into an object which I can then plot in an overlay on top of something like `boxplot(frame$x2~fact)` where I want to explicitly see the first or last or nth element.

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong, but trying to get this code to run, I am getting an error "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'firstx2' not found".  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Bob: it could be how you've created `frame`.  I've added a `frame` example to my answer.

Comment: thanks, I am a bit unclear though as to what transform bit does.  The built-in R-lang help is not very useful here, saying "transform is a generic function, which—at least currently—only does anything useful with data frames".  Why is it necessary for your solution?

Comment: @Bob: `transform` is just a syntactic short-cut.  I've added lines that do the same thing.